# mongodb aggregate query with nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb

I have n houses, each house has streetid, houseid, neighborhoodid

{streetid,houseid,neighborhood}

{av,1,A},{av,2,A},{av,3,A}

{av,5,B},{av,6,B},{av,7,B}

{rd,1,A},{rd,22,A},{rd,33,A}

I want to group by street so that each street will have an array of neighborhoods (a street can span several neighborhoods ) and each neighborhood will have a list of houses that are in it(the houses must also belong to the street)

the result should be something like

{av,[{A ,[1,2,3]}, {B,[5,6,7]}]}

// street A spans neighborhood A and B each with its houses

{rd,[{A ,[1,22,33]}]}

// street rd spans neighborhood A  with its houses

Comment: Your documents are not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.example.aggregate( [
  { 
    $group: { 
      _id:   { neighbourhood: "$neighbourhood", streetId: "$streetId" }, 
      house: { $addToSet: "$houseId" } 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: { street: "$_id.streetId" }, 
      housesInNeighbourHood: { $addToSet: { neighbourhoodId: "$_id.neighbourhood", houseId:"$house" } } 
    } 
  } 
])
```